Displaying User Name from JWT Token in React Header with C# Backend
I want to properly display the userName in the Header component. However, I sometimes encounter errors while decoding the token with jwtDecode, or the setUserName state is not updated correctly.
Do I need additional validation for the token from the backend, or am I handling the token incorrectly in the frontend?
What is the correct way to extract the user's name from the JWT token and display it in the Header component?
How can I improve my code for both the frontend and backend?
I also want to ensure that there are no security vulnerabilities in my implementation.

provide some of your already existing code ( which is not working ). If you've tried any other variations, provide them as well. for example: different part of code ( header component, where and how you're decoding, where you're showing username ).

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Maybe you can think about creating an endpoint to fetch the details of users for your project.
Here are the steps below
Backend steps

Create an endpoint in C# Backend
Find the user from the information in token (I don't know what details you're putting to your token)
Fetch the user details from your database
Create a DTO to send suitable data to your react app

React App Steps

Take the token wherever you're reading it
Send a request to your endpoint with your token
Take your response and show the username in your header.

You can also save your user data in a main provider so that you can access wherever you want inside of your app.
Hope this helps!
